# Finding two points' center of mass on a sphere (k-means on a sphere)

Tags: geometry, k-means

Please, help me to solve subproblem in my programming task (k-means clustering on a sphere).

Suppose the Earth is a sphere. And there are two points (we know their latitudes and longitudes) with masses m_1 and m_2 on it.

The problem is to find latitude and longitude of these two points' center of mass on a sphere, if the distance is measured as [the great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a point that lies on the great circle arc at distance

```
l = L * m1 / (m1 + m2)
```

from the first point, where L is full distance between points.
You can use or
[spherical linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) : translate spherical coordinates to Descartes' coordinate system, work with vectors, translate back
or
geodesic approach - find bearing from the first point to the second, find distance L, and move distance l with bearing found. All formulae are at this page: [Destination point given distance and bearing from start point](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll try the second approach.